# Api Controller Ignores DataMember On Deserialize

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dto

I have a CaptionDto class with ItemId property.
When serializing this object to return to the browser I want the ItemId name to change to TranslationId and vice versa.
My problem is that it works only for the serialize phase but not for the deserialize phase.

```js
    [DataContract]
    public class CaptionDto
    {
        [DataMember]
        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "TranslationId", IsRequired =true)]
        public System.Guid ItemId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public long StartTimeMilisec { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public long EndTimeMilisec { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string FirstLine { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string SecondLine { get; set; }
   }
   
   
     [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult>  Get(itemId)
        {
            var captionDtos = await getByItemId(itemId)
            //Serialize works fine and ItemId does change to TranslationId
            return Ok(captionDtos);
        }
       
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(CaptionDto captionDto)
        {
          //Here captionDto doesn't contains the ItemId altough it is being sent
        }
```

Comment: Can you please post the JSON you are trying to deserialize

Comment: You may have to create a mapper using ContractResolver if you are using Newtonsoft JSON